# Does `config.requre_master_key = false` in production cause any problem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

My application is created by Rails 5.2.2, and it requires master.key when I build assets even though it doesn't use actually. I provide my application as docker image, so I need to build it while creating the image, but I don't want to include my master.key in it. I also know actually needed is secret_key_base, so I tried to expose dummy SECRET_KEY_BASE as environment variable, but `bundle exec rails assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` is failed because there is `config.require_master_key = true` in my config file. I think if this settings turn to false, the application doesn't check whether master.key exists or not, and it will work fine. But I don't know why default value is true, so I can't decide to do it.
Does `config.requre_master_key = false` cause any problem? Can anyone help me?

Comment: I have a 5.2.2.1 app running in production and `config.require_master_key = true` was commented out by default in `production.rb`. It should be fine to comment it out. If its not, I'm sure it will yell at you.

Comment: thank you for your comment. I almost forgot that the configuration is commented out by default, so your comment is helpful for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, this is config file, and you can change the value for it but if you get any errors then you may find a workaround for this here
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/32947

`` SECRET_KEY_BASE=`bin/rake secret` bin/rake assets:precompile ``